# RxJS Subscription and code execution in it

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

In many projects, I see this kind of subscription code:

```
isLoading: boolean; // the variable initializes, for instance, the display of the loader
```

The next step is to load the content of the page:

```
this.loadSomething(): void {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.someService.getMethod(data)
  .subscribe(response => {
      if (response) {
      ...do something
      }
    },
    (errors: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      ...do something
    },
    () => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  );
};
```

As far as I know, the third `.complete()` subscription argument will not be executed in case of an error.
Thus, if we receive an error from the server, `this.isLoading = false;` will not be executed and we will not see the data page, and we will see an infinite loader.

In my code I always write like this:

```
this.loadSomething(): void {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.someService.getMethod(data)
  .subscribe(response => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      if (response) {
      ...do something
      }
    },
    (errors: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      ...do something
    }
  );
};
```

..that is, without using the `.complete()` block

I can't figure out why it's written this way or am I missing something?
How do you subscribe and how do you do it correctly?

Comment: Not sure if it's related to the issue that it's bugging you or not, but mind the fact that you have a "this." in in front of your "loadSomething" method declaration. It should be loadSomething(): void { ... }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `finalize` operator to handle loading disablement, it'll run after upon `complete` or `error`

```
this.someService.getMethod(data).
pipe(finalize(()=>this.loading=false))
.subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.someService.getMethod(data).subscribe(this.observer)


detectChanges() {
  this.loading = false;
  this.ref.detectChanges(); // if you are using OnPush strategy
}

 observer = {
  next: (data) => {
    // do stuff
    console.log(data);
    this.detectChanges()
  },
  error: (error) => {
     // do stuff
     // throw httpResponseError or treat error here
     console.log(error)
     this.detectChanges()
  },
  complete: () => {
     console.log("data has been loaded")
     this.detectChanges()
  }
}
```